# what's the difference between struct cdev and struct device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Could anybody can give me some explanation about the difference between the `struct cdev` and `struct device`?

Answer (score 4):

At the lowest level, **every device** in a Linux system is represented by an instance of `struct device`. The device structure contains the information that the device model core needs to model the system. Most subsystems, however, track additional information about the devices they host. As a result, it is rare for devices to be represented by bare device structures; instead, that structure, like kobject structures, is usually embedded within a higher-level representation of the device.
[more](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-struct-device.html)

`struct cdev`,however, is a structure which is used by kernel to represent **character devices** internally.
[more](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-4)

Comment: thank you~ one more issue that whether it's better that the `struct device`embedded in `struct cdev`?

Comment: `struct device` and `struct cdev` are kernel's internel structures and embedding one in another means that you are modifying kernel code which will have serious consequences. Instead you may embed both `struct device` and `struct cdev` in your device's main structure. e.g [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/fuse/cuse.c#L56)

Comment: Also see **Device Structure Embedding** in [LDD3](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch14.pdf) Page:383